# Matrix Represenation Problem

Tags: linear-algebra

> I have the following Problem:

[image]

> And that should be the answer of the problem, however I cannot understand it, could someone explain it?

[image]

Comment: Please stop putting your questions into pictures. It is a requirement that you format your questions using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). You've asked 29 questions over 8 months; it's time to learn Latex!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First note that$$T(X)=XB=\begin{bmatrix}x_1&x_2\\x_3&x_4\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}b_1&b_2\\b_3&b_4\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}x_1b_1+x_2b_3&x_1b_2+x_2b_4\\x_3b_1+x_4b_3&x_3b_2+x_4b_4\end{bmatrix}$$where $b_i$s are known constants.

$T$ is a linear operator on a $4$-dimensional vector space, so the matrix of $T$ will be $4\times4$. Note that when you find the image of a point under a linear transformation, you multiply the matrix of the linear transformation with the **column vector** representing that point. The result is also a column vector representing the image. In our case, the domain and codomain is the set of real $2\times2$ matrices, which are not column vectors, so we have to devise a way to represent them as column vectors. The conventional way to do so is to represent the matrix$$\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}$$by the column vector$$\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\\d\end{bmatrix}$$Thus, you have $$T(X)=A\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\\x_4\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}x_1b_1+x_2b_3\\x_1b_2+x_2b_4\\x_3b_1+x_4b_3\\x_3b_2+x_4b_4\end{bmatrix}$$where $A$ is the matrix of $T$. Can you now find $A$?